# AngularJs use object available by $scope from one function to another

Tags: angularjs

I am getting Problem to get department object which is available in `$scope.setDepartment` in my code. I want help to solve this problem as soon as possible.

```
$scope.editableAttendance = {};
        $scope.attendanceList = [];

        var refreshList = function () {
            console.log("1 ", $stateParams.departmentId);
            $scope.attendanceList = EmployeeService.findByDepartmentId({
                'departmentId': $scope.editableAttendance.id
            }, function () {
                angular.forEach($scope.attendanceList, function (attendance) {
                    attendance.dep = DepartmentService.get({
                        'id': attendance.departmentId
                    });
                    attendance.emp = EmployeeService.get({
                        'id': attendance.id
                    });
                });
            });
        };

        $scope.setDepartment = function (department) {
            $scope.editableAttendance = department;
            console.log("department in function", $scope.editableAttendance);
        };
        console.log("department outside function ", $scope.editableAttendance);

        refreshList();
```

Here I am setting department from frontend using `$scope.setDepartment` function so here i am getting whole department object in `$scope.editableAttendance` in that particular method `$scope.setDepartment`.
now I want to use id from that object or i want that whole object available outside `$scope.setDepartment` method so that I can use department object in my refreshList() function.
Means whatever department object I am getting in setDepartment function, I want to use it in another function.

Comment: You can use $scope.editableAttendance in your refreshList function without any problem,.... ensure $scope.editableAttendance = {} is defiend at the top of your code...

Comment: @ Thalaivar yes, but i am not getting $scope.editableAttendance in refreshList function `$scope.attendanceList = EmployeeService.findByDepartmentId({
                'departmentId': $scope.editableAttendance.id
            },`

Comment: here that department console inside function getting whole object but when i am trying to print outside in console "department outside function" there i am getting null object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its simple, here there are two functions, and we have to make available object of one function in another function.
so call `refreshList` function in `setDepartment` so key `departmentId` can access id from object `$scope.editableAttendance`.
it define as follow,

```
$scope.setDepartment = function (department) {
     $scope.editableAttendance = department;
     refreshlist();
};
```

so that `refreshList` function should access `$scope.editableAttendance`.